# maximum value for type float in c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, notation

When I do this:

```
float x = float.MaxValue;
```

I have the result: 3.40282347E+38

What is E+38? how can I represent the maximum number without this symbol?

msdn says RANGE: ±1.5 × 10^−45 to ±3.4 × 10^38, but that did not help me.

Comment: Do you wish to represent this in a string? What do you mean by "represent"?

Answer (score 39):

The "E+38" format is the default.  If you'd like to see the whole number, specify a different format like this:

```
float.MaxValue.ToString("#")
```

This will result in:

```
340282300000000000000000000000000000000
```

Here are some additional formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx

Comment: No problem.  If you want commas, use `"#,#"` or `"N"`.

Comment: The "whole number" is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.

Comment: @Dan The best answer I have seen in questions like this. Can you show how to do this in C++?

Answer (score 13):

This is called [E-Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) (exponential notation), and is used with scientific notation.

From the [E Notation section of the Wikipedia article on Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation):

> Because super-scripted exponents like 10^7 cannot always be
>   conveniently displayed, the letter E or e is often used to represent
>   times ten raised to the power of (which would be written as "x 10^b")
>   and is followed by the value of the exponent.

So, `3.40282347E+38` equals `3.40282347 * 10`<sup>`38`</sup> and would be read "3.40282347 times 10 to the power of 38".

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code:

```
float f = float.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine("Origianl Value: " + f);
Console.WriteLine("With Zeros:" + f.ToString("0"));
```

Value

```
Origianl Value: 3.402823E+38
With Zeros:340282300000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

That is [Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

```
5E+2 = 
5 x 10 ^ 2 = 
5 x 10 * 10 = 
5 * 100 =
500
```

In other words, that's how many decimal places you move the decimal point to calculate the result. Take 5, move it over 2 places, end up with 500. In your example, you need to take your number, `3.40282347` and move the decimal place over 38 times!

Answer (score 1):

3.4e38 is 3.4 * 10^38 or 340000000000 ... (37 zeros)

additional information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's approx. 340 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000

If you use Dan's code, you'll get this as a result:

```
340282300000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of the float without exponent is: 340282356779733661637539395458142568447.9f

Comment: I think the c# compiler allows you to define that as a constant but after compilation it is truncated to float.maxvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here's the min and max in string format.

```
Using float.Parse
-340282356779733642999999999999999999999 to 340282356779733642999999999999999999999
Using float.MinValue.ToString("#") and float.MaxValue.ToString("#")
-340282300000000000000000000000000000000 to 340282300000000000000000000000000000000
Using float.MinValue.ToString() and float.MaxValue.ToString()
-3.402823E+38 to 3.402823E+38
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro an old thread but google lead me here and I didn't find a satisfactory answer. I'm sure google will lead someone else here.

The float.h library includes the maximum values for float and others in c. FLOAT_MAX is equal to 340282346638528859811704183484516925440, that is the maximum value that float can store.

I'm not an expert in C but I would imagine this value is universal and wouldn't depend on a x32 or x64 operating system.

Comment: (a) `FLT_MAX` -- not `FLOAT_MAX` -- actually _does_ vary from system to system, or compiler to compiler, although it's at *least* 1E+37 (b) this question is about C#, not C.

Comment: first, this should be its own question. second, the max value of an IEEE floating point value is defined by international standard. it's impossible to store "all values in range" within a 32bit space and loss of precision occurs values greater than approximately 2^24 -- a similar loss of precision happens to fraction values. again this is because the available binary space for storage, and, .NET follows IEEE 754-1985 rounding rules. A new standard was published in 2008. Either way, float can store values greater than `340282346638528859811704183484516925440` with significant loss of precision.

Comment: this is neither language-specific nor platform/architecture-specific. the choice of what to provide in constants found in various sources is not dictated by IEEE standard, and will vary. by spec, the FLT_MAX in your C distribution is technically incorrect, it is too large a value to store in a 32bit space and necessarily would be rounded. the largest normal integer which can be stored in a 32bit space (unsigned)  is  4,294,967,295 (anything greater than this demands loss of precision.)

Answer (score 0):

The answers showing `float.MaxValue` using `ToString` are not correct.

Those answers state `float.MaxValue` is :
`var f1 = 340282300000000000000000000000000000000f;`

That is only is what C# produces when converting `float.MaxValue` to string.

However, `float.MaxValue` is defined in `System.Single` as `3.40282347E+38F`

So the actual answer is:

`var f2 = 340282347000000000000000000000000000000f;`

Also note, a compile defect will allow constant values higher than this to be used as a float. However upon compliation, C# will trunacted those values to `float.MaxValue`. For example:

```
var f3 = 340282356699999999999999999999999999999f;
var f4 = 340282356760000000000000000000000000000f;
var f5 = 340282356779733661637539395458142568447.9f;
```

Here f5 (`340282356779733661637539395458142568447.9f`) is the actual maximum constant you can define. Again, this is truncated to `float.MaxValue`.

This can all be verified:

```
var equals_1 = f1 == f; // false
var equals_2 = f2 == float.MaxValue; // true
var equals_3 = f3 == float.MaxValue; // true
var equals_4 = f3 == float.MaxValue; // true
var equals_4 = f5 == float.MaxValue; // true
```