# Convert a string to float

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a string in this format: `"123.46.789-01"`. I must cast it to float, and I was doing it this way: `float.parse(stringVariable.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", ""))` where `stringVariable` is the string with the value described above.

This cast is generating a wrong cast value, wich is `1.141085E+10`.

I've tried converting in many other ways, like `Convert.ToSingle`, but no success on that. You guys can help me with that? I'm wondering if this kind of number fits on float data type at all...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your expected value?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, it returns the correct value for me.

Comment: You should specify culture in your parse operation. User culture, or invariant culture if its technical data.

Comment: I think you made a little mistake, try: 
`stringVariable = stringVariable.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
float f = Convert.ToSingle(stringVariable);`

Comment: the expected value is "12345678901". I've triedt to specify the culture but makes no difference in this case... I'll try your suggestion, user2754599.

EDIT
Already tried your suggestion, user2754599, but makes no difference.

Comment: @Johann I've pretty sure that this does not involve culture at all, the string we parse is just a numeric string, so what's the difference between cultures?

Comment: Try doing it as a double. `double.Parse("12345678901")` works fine on csharpfiddle.com.

Comment: I get the same value as OP, running it in LINQPad.

Comment: @SteveB I don't think culture is necessary to specify, as the value is not decimal(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of problems using floats. I tend to use doubles, which does the same thing(?)

When I run:

```
var inputString = "123.46.789-01";
var strippedString = inputString.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");
float floatValue = float.Parse(strippedString);
```

I get the value: `1,234679E+09` which is an alternative way of displaying `1234678901`.

Confirm by adding this line to the code:

```
double doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(floatValue);
```

and you'll get `1234678901`.

Comment: This code is part of a big system... I can not change the datatype right now... Maybe if I can prove that this size of number (99.999.999.999) can't fit on a float, I get the approval to do it.

Comment: @Johann see my updated answer, do you get the same behaviour? Regarding Max-value of floats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857797/maximum-value-for-type-float-in-c-sharp

Comment: I haven't realized this... But when you save this kind of number, 1,234679E+09, on the database, in a float column, you get the same value? the big picture is that I'm getting another number when this kind of number is stored on the database (SQL SERVER 2008).

Comment: Well it is a general problem with floating numbers, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005725/save-float-values-in-sql-server

Comment: OK. So maybe the float datatype is not a reliable datatype to store this kind of number, huh? EDIT: I've tried to vote up your response, but I don't have the minimum reputation to do it ;)

Comment: No, I wouldn't use floats, you will get unpredictable results - and that might get you the approval you need! You don't need upvote when you can mark it as the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and is more general (as I am removing all non-digits):

```
float result = float.Parse(Regex.Replace(str, "[^0-9]", ""));
```

Comment: The only possibility of non-digits in this case are the chars "." and "-", no need to make a more general... The cast failed, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this! i am getting output **1234678901**

```
string cpf = "123.46.789-01";
decimal result= decimal.Parse(Regex.Replace(cpf, "[^0-9]", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

Comment: Yes, works to cast to a decimal data type... the datatype that I must use is float...